# Unable to access object attribute values using Twig in Symfony 2.2

Tags: php, oop, symfony, web, twig

I cannot access the objects properties using the Twig dot notation. For example, from looking at the object dump, I should be able to do image.copyright, which should print "Blue button near the Cayman Islands, Caribbean (© Lawson Wood/Aurora Photos)" for the first item.

The error message I get is

> Method "copyright" for object "SimpleXMLElement" does not exist in ARRaiDesignBundle:Default:wallpapers.html.twig at line 12

While dumping the object using dump(image) dumps each of the objects.

Controller class:

```
$host = 'http://www.bing.com';
$file = $host . '/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=xml&idx=0&n=10&mkt=en-US';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);

return $this->render('ARRaiDesignBundle:Default:wallpapers.html.twig', array('xml' => $xml, 'host' => $host));
```

wallpapers.html.twig file:

```
...
{% for image in xml %}
<p><pre>{{ image.copyright }}</pre></p>
{% endfor %}
...
```

Object dump using dump(image) in Twig:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#268 (12) {
  ["startdate"]=>
  string(8) "20130330"
  ["fullstartdate"]=>
  string(12) "201303300000"
  ["enddate"]=>
  string(8) "20130331"
  ["url"]=>
  string(46) "/az/hprichbg/rb/BlueButton_EN-US1108621411.jpg"
  ["urlBase"]=>
  string(43) "/az/hprichbg/rb/BlueButton_EN-US10208337365"
  ["copyright"]=>
  string(77) "Blue button near the Cayman Islands, Caribbean (© Lawson Wood/Aurora Photos)"
  ["copyrightlink"]=>
  string(74) "http://www.bing.com/search?q=Blue+Button+%28Porpita+porpita%29&form=hpcapt"
  ["drk"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["top"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["bot"]=>
  string(1) "1"
...
```

Can anyone suggest how to do this? I know I can use PHP rendering instead of Twig, but that's not a fix for me. Thanks.

Comment: Here is the line in the source that outputs that line: https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/blob/master/lib/Twig/Template.php#L424

Comment: Have you tried [casting `$xml` to an `array`](http://codepad.org/s4tFbNvM)?

Comment: @JaredFarrish I used the data you provided with simplexml_load_string($file). It seems symfony does not like bing's xml. As within <images> there is also <tooltips>. Which is a werid structure to iterate through. Although, standard php is fine, but twigs function is not perfect.

Comment: You should search for whether there's an issue, and report it if there's not one for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening due to Bing's werid XML structure, the last bit is not iterative friendly. With standard PHP it's fine, but with Twig, it doesn't catch the errors for the last element.

```
<images>
<image>...</image>
<image>...</image>
<image>...</image>
<image>...</image>
<image>...</image>
<image>...</image>
<image>...</image>
<image>...</image>
<tooltips>...</tooltips>
</images>
```

To fix this, I just unset tooltips. "unset($xml->tooltips)"

Thanks @JaredFarrish for providing clean xml. :)

Answer (score 3):

with example php doc http://www.php.net/manual/fr/simplexml.examples-basic.php
in twig, to get attribute 'type' from 'rating' item, use attributes (="@attributes") like :

```
{% for rating in movies.movie.rating %}
   {{ rating.attributes.type }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your `SimpleXMLElement` does not have magic methods implemented. When you call in Twig `object.property` - it invokes `getProperty()` method of your `object`. Try do access property directly in Twig:

```
{{ image['copyright'] }}
```

Comment: I've tried that already, does not work: Key "copyright" in object (with ArrayAccess) of type "SimpleXMLElement" does not exist in ARRaiDesignBundle:Default:wallpapers.html.twig at line 12

Comment: Probably one of your objects really doesn't have such property? Have you tried to iterate it with `default` filter? `{{ image['copyright']|default('') }}`

Comment: @AmarjeetSinghRai otherwise you can try to dump each object from loop using twig and see what properties are accessible - `{{ dump(image) }}`

Comment: That then displays nothing. It does exist, look at the object dump above. I managed to display it perfectly without symfony.

Comment: that is how I got the object dump in twig. [Above]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to proxy that object. Create a new object that wraps the SimpleXMLElement object and define a getCopyright() method.

```
class Element 
{
    protected $xmlElement;
    public function getCopyright() 
    {
        return $this->xmlElement->copyright;
    }
}
```